# Map was displayed in External Browser but not in viewer Pane

Tags: javascript, html, r, google-maps, shiny

I am new to both shiny and google map API. App displays the map in **External mode** but **not** in **Window or Viewer  Pane.**

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My Map"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("coordinates","Coordinate"),
      actionButton("updateMap", "Mark the Place")
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      includeHTML("www/ui.html")
    )
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$updateMap, {
    print(input$updateMap)
  })
})
```

**ui.html** in **www** directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var counter = 0;  
      function placeddMarkers(lat = 44.5403, lng = -78.5463) {
          var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,
            icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
          });  
      }     

      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
         map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);             

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="placeddMarkers()">The time is?</button>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

After removing **placeddMarkers** definition from ui.html everything seems to work properly. Why is it so? Is the problem is with shiny or I am doing something wrong. Please help.